# Looping through child elements of a loop of parent elements

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a set of divs that I'd like to loop through and within that I'd like to loop through child elements (several levels of nesting here).

If I do:

```
puts browser.div(:class => 'layout4').element(:class => 'event-info').text
```

then I correctly get the text of the child element that I want so I've tried to pluralize it like this:

```
browser.divs(:class => 'layout4').each do |event|
    browser.event.elements(:class => 'event-info') do |game|
        puts game.text
    end
end
```

but the inner loop there doesn't run at all.

Comment: Since the first .each is sending the watir div objects into the loop as 'event', you really don't need to start with the browser inside the loop.  `event.elements(:class => 'event-info').each do |game|` should work just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the 'each' on the inner loop

```
browser.divs(:class => 'layout4').each do |event|
    browser.event.elements(:class => 'event-info').each do |game|
        puts game.text
    end
end
```